# How to wrap around part of text inside an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, word-wrap

Let's say I have the sentence:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

inside a `<p>` tag. I would like to somehow use javascript to create an element around the word `amet`, e.g.:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span>amet</span>, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Is there some sort of way to do this?  In the real-world application for this, I won't know what text I want to have an element around, so I can't just modify the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `replace` method.

```
$('p').html(function(index, oldHtml){
   return oldHtml.replace(/(amet)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YxMvq/

Comment: What is the "i" parameter for?

Comment: @AndrewBriggs `Index` of selected elements in jQuery collection.

Comment: What is the "g" for?  I tried removing it, and it works fine without it.