# substring selector with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to select only part of a string using jquery? For example I have a text

```
<p>Metuentes igitur idem latrones Lycaoniam magna parte campestrem</p>
```

So now if the user search for a string, I want it to be highlighted (we use a bold tag for example)

```
<p>Metuentes igitur idem latrones <b>Lycaoniam</b> magna parte campestrem</p>
```

And then we can revert back to original string if needed.

1. The first question is whether we can select a substring like this using jQuery, and use jQuery method such as `.css()` to apply style to that element.
2. The second question is if we don't have such selector, how can we achieve it using jQuery or javascript through string manipulation

Thanks.

**UPDATED**

Thank for everyone effort. Here is a small program, final result of what I'm looking for http://jsfiddle.net/TPg9p/3/ Cheers!

Comment: I don't think jQuery can select the sub-string as it is not a html element. You could select the p element, and then use .html() to get the current string, manipulate that string in JavaScript adding in a <b> and </b> tag where needed, then setting the html of the p again using .html(newHtmlVariable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with pure jQuery. You could do this instead :

```
var search = 'Lycaoniam';
var orig = $('p').html();
var highlighted = orig.replace(new RegExp(
    search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'gi'
), '<b>$&</b>');
$('p').html(highlighted);
```

To revert back to the original text :

```
$('p').html(orig);
```

The `search.replace(...)` part allows to deal with special chars : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/TPg9p/.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/Lycaoniam/gi` ?

Comment: That's quite long for a regexp string. Could you explain a bit what it matches? And why `$&` but not `$1` or `$number`

Comment: @ThanhTrung For the long regex see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/1636522. For `$&` see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Comment: Not work => http://jsfiddle.net/GeyvD/1/ I think the original string has to be escaped first

Comment: @ThanhTrung I guess you have to escape backslashes. I've added a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/TPg9p/.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the element in which to search:

```
var string = "Lycaoniam";
var e = $("elementSelector"); // put here your selector
e.html(e.html().replace(new RegExp(search, "gi"), "<b>"+search+"</b>"));
```

for more elements, simply loop through them and do the replacing. To make a toggable styling, I'd use a custom class:

```
 e.html(e.html().replace(new RegExp(search, "gi"), "<span class='highlight'>"+search+"</span>"));
```

and remove it with:

```
$(".highlight").contents().unwrap();
```

*.contents().unwrap()* does the trick of stripping not only the class (which must be styled accordingly) but also the tag.

Comment: +1 for using unwrap trick. We don't need to store the original value!

Comment: Yes but I made a mistake, my code would substitute only the 1st occurrence. Now it should be ok with a RegExp :)

Comment: This works in the given case, but will fail if the search string contains regexp string

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from here: [Wrap around part of text inside an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676642/wrap-around-part-of-text-inside-an-element)

you could do the following:

```
$('p').html(function(index, oldHtml){
   return oldHtml.replace(/(amet)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YxMvq/

Comment: No, that's not string selector. You don't get my question

Comment: This works in the given case, but will fail if the search string contains regexp string

Answer (score 1):

Search for the text and replace the text.

**HTML :**

```
<p id="mainText">Metuentes igitur idem latrones Lycaoniam magna parte campestrem</p>
<input type="text" id="inputTextBox" />
<input type="button" id="findButton" value="Find" />
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#findButton").click(function(){
    var inputText = $("#inputTextBox").val();
    var mainText = $("#mainText").text();
    var updatedText = "<b>" + inputText + "</b>";
    mainText = mainText.replace(inputText, updatedText);
    $("#mainText").html(mainText);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/jLP22/)

Comment: This will replace only 1st occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know when the HTML is created which word you want? Then I would suggest doing the following instead

```
<p>Metuentes igitur idem latrones <span class="js-highlightable">Lycaoniam</span> magna parte campestrem</p>`
```

now if you wanna highlight it just do

```
$(".js-highlightable").toggleClass("highlighted");
```

Any styles can be defined in the `highligthed` class. You could also use an `id` for the span instead if you want to be able to apply the change to only that single element and not all elements with `js-highlightable` class.

Comment: We don't know in advance which string the user is searching for so it's useless to wrap a span around a word in advance

Comment: In addition, toggleClass would remove the class but not the span. And the span, if I got the OP's intentions right, should not be present in the beginning. I've posted above what I think is a better solution.

Comment: Yupp absolutely, my solution is based on knowing beforehand what element should be able to be highligthed. I will leave the answer here if someone else has a similar problem where my solution is applicable.